# How to resolve "Failed to set data" error when writing a String value in the Windows Registry?

Tags: delphi, registry

When trying to write a value in the windows registry I get a "Failed to set data for "Value1" " error. I tried running the program as a administrator, creating the key manually and setting the permisions of the key for "Everyone" to full acess. But the error persists

I have used the following code to write the value:

```
var
   Registry: TRegistry;
 begin
   Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
     Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

     // False because otherwise it would create a new key
     try
     if not Registry.OpenKey(KeyLocation, True) then RaiseLastOSError;
     Registry.WriteString('Value1', 'text123');
    finally
      Registry.Free;
     end;
end;
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the value in `KeyLocation` correct, have you checked ? Does it has the correct slashes (I think it should also end with a slash in this case)

Comment: @GuidoG The value is correct, and the apropriate slashes are included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write registry to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` branch part of the registry. This is a system level part of the registry that requires elevated privileges to be accessible.

Or in other words you will have to run your application as administrator or request privileges elevation using manifest file.

EDIT: Also you are opening the registry with `KEY_READ` access level which is only used for reading the registry but not writing to the registry.

You can read more about Access levels [here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.Access)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can't use the parameter-less overload of `RaiseLastOSError()` with `TRegistry`, because the Registry API doesn't report errors via the Win32 `GetLastError()` function.  Registry API functions return error codes directly to the caller.  `TRegistry` captures those error codes in its [`LastError`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.LastError) property, which you can then pass to one of the other overloads of `RaiseLastOSError()`, eg:

```pascal
if not Registry.OpenKey(KeyLocation, True) then
  RaiseLastOSError(Registry.LastError);
```

That being said, you are opening the key for **read-only** access, but are then trying to **write** to the key.  That is likely why `WriteString()` is failing.  You need to use `KEY_WRITE` instead, or better just `KEY_SET_VALUE` (since `KEY_WRITE` includes permissions that `WriteString()` doesn't need in this particular situation), eg:

```pascal
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_SET_VALUE{KEY_WRITE});
  try
    Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

    if not Registry.OpenKey(KeyLocation, True) then
      RaiseLastOSError(Registry.LastError);

    Registry.WriteString('Value1', 'text123');
  finally
    Registry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, do note that you are trying to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, which by default only admins have write access to.  So yes, you will have to either run your code with elevated rights, or else adjust the Registry permissions to grant write access to a non-admin user and then run your code as that user.

Also, if you are running on a 64bit machine, you might need to explicitly specify whether you want to access the 32bit (`KEY_WOW64_32KEY`) or 64bit (`KEY_WOW64_32KEY`) section of the Registry.  See [Accessing An Alternate Registry View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view).

Comment: This worked for most hives but I cant edit any sub-key of SOFTWARE, even with a `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` permission. Why is that?

Comment: `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` requires admin access

Comment: I had the app running as administrator thought.

Comment: Running as an admin user, and running with elevated admin rights, is too different things. But, if `OpenKey()` succeeds with `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` and `WriteString()` still fails, you simply just don't have write access to that particular key.

Comment: Admin user like having my account as a system administrator?

Comment: Even if your user is part of Administrator group you still have to specifically select `Run as administrator` in order to run the application with elevated rights or make sure that your application manifest automatically request permissions elevation.